# How to call a js function when url contains anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a site example.com.
When I visit this page example.com/#login I want to call a js alert function.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

```
// example.com/#login
if (window.location.hash) {
    alert("URL has hash");
    var hash = window.location.hash; // = "#login"
    callMyFunction();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a good cross-browser library for dealing with url's, I'd look into History.js

https://github.com/browserstate/History.js/

```
History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function(){ 
    // Note: We are using statechange instead of popstate
    var State = History.getState(); 
    // Note: We are using History.getState() instead of event.state
    History.log(State.data, State.title, State.url);
});
```

And there's also Backbone.js, which may be way more than you need because it's an MV* framework, however it has a concept of a Router which is also helpful.

http://backbonejs.org/#Router

Answer (score 0):

You can check the URL for #login. If it's present call the function.
http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum91/216.htm

I recommend jQuery, and this approach:
http://jquery-howto.blogspot.co.uk/2009/09/get-url-parameters-values-with-jquery.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you can check if `window.location.hash` isn't a falsy value to check if there is a hash in the URL.

For example:

```
function someAlert(message) {
    // This would be your alert function. This is just for example
    alert(message);
}
// The "if the URL has a hash":
if (window.location.hash) {
    someAlert("Hello URL with a hash visitor!"); // "Hello URL with a hash visitor!" can be whatever you want
}
```

If you want to save the whatever is after and including the hash, just use:

```
var hash = window.location.hash; // hash would be "#login" if the URL was http://example.com/#login
```